# Java desktop application connect to GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

i'm trying to connect a desktop application in java to google app engine using the javax servlet. But I'm not sure what to do.

the webserver manager for login is like this

```
 public class UserServicesP3Servlet extends HttpServlet 
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
{       
    doGet(req,resp);
}
```

and in a browser i connect using

```
else if(address.indexOf("/dinamicas/login")!=-1)
    {
            StringMaisAutenticado sma = Autenticacao.login(req,resp,param1,param2);
            resposta = sma.string;
            utilizadorAutenticado = sma.utilizadorAutent;
    }
```

I'm not really sure what to do in the desktop to login. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tune up your app's authentication options in [three ways](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/auth.html):

1. using google accounts
2. users of google apps
3. using OpenID

Applying to your situation, you can authenticate users like

```
UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService(); 
User user = userService.getCurrentUser(); 
if (user == null) 
    response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
```

Next you can authorize access to their data using [AuthSub](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html) or [OAuth](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/oauth/overview.html).

I hope this helps.